# Plugin name for showing indentation guide in gVim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Anybody, any idea??

which plugin is showing the indentation guide in the image below. Downloaded from http://leetless.de/images/vim/pyte.png

[image]

[image: Vertical indent guide marked with Black lines].png

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A similar effect could be achieved with:

```
set list
set listchars+=tab:\│┈
```

Maybe with another filler character.

See `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars'`.

**But…**

As I was writing that answer it appeared to me that the answer was probably in the colorscheme's author's `~/.vimrc`.

I think that you should **really** work on sharpening your deduction skills. It takes about 30 seconds to 1 minute to find that information by yourself:

1. Go to the site where you get that pic from: http://leetless.de
2. Look around for something Vim-related. The navigation is generally the first place to go and what do you find? "Vim themes" at http://leetless.de/vim.html
3. That image illustrates the first "theme" featured, that's a good sign. But let's read the introduction text (emphasis mine, typos his):

   > If you are curious what some other things are *(like the indetation markers)* and how they work, take a look at [my .vimrc](http://leetless.de/vimrc.txt). Note that the encoding is broken with that file so the *"set lcs"* part is probably not copy-pasteable, follow the instructions in the comments above that line in order to find out how you can make your own unicode-lcs.

   Wow! It looks like you are getting closer to the truth. Beware of the Cigarette Man!
4. Follow the link and do a search for `lcs`.
5. Done.

Comment: Yeah I'm working on improving my deduction skill.

set lcs=tab:â”‚â”ˆ,trail:Â·,extends:>,precedes:<,nbsp:&

Do you have idea about the codepoint used for all these?

Comment: Is that a real question? Everything is explained on the page *and* in the linked `.vimrc`.

Comment: There are many characters used. But only one code  point is mentioned.

Comment: All the characters used are valid utf-8 characters. If you don't like them, find other ones. How to do that is explained in the vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "indentation guide", but I don't think any plugin is involved.

The first thing I see that you might be referring to is the characters at the beginning of lines indicating where there are tabs.  That can be done by doing setting the `listchars` option to an appropriate value, turning the `list` option on, and selecting a color for the `SpecialKey` highlight group.

The other thing you might be referring to is highlighting of the column that currently contains the cursor.  That can be done by turning on the `cursorcolumn` option.  The color used for that can be set with the `CursorColumn` highlight group.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a plugin, [vim-indent-guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides)

Comment: Yes  I have installed that. But didn't find anything similar to Codekane (VS 2005 plugin) indent guide in visual studio or similar to notepad++ indent guide

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice plugin for vim: https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine